# C Alias to C# assistanc

Tags: c#, c, alias

Working on a hobby project to convert an old C application to C#.

In C they would define constants/alias like such:

```
#define args( list )            list
#define DECLARE_DO_FUN( fun )       DO_FUN    fun
#define DECLARE_SPEC_FUN( fun )     SPEC_FUN  fun
#define DECLARE_SPELL_FUN( fun )    SPELL_FUN fun
void    init_descriptor     args( ( int control ) );
bool    read_from_descriptor    args( ( DESCRIPTOR_DATA *d ) );
bool    write_to_descriptor args( ( int desc, char *txt, int length ) );
```

What would be the equivalent in C#?

As i am not keen on Ansi-C anymore (last time was mid-90s), need others to help with some of the signature conversions.

Comment: `using Something = SomeNamespace.SomeType;`, no?

Comment: What equivalent to code in C#? There is no constants nor alias in your sample, only function declarations. Side note: it may be easier (depending on size of the project) to simply write C# code from scratch... Converting potentially procedural C code to reasonably object oriented C# code may be as complex as rewrite.

Comment: For posterity, the args macro was a trick that was used to get the code working with ancient C compilers.  The Diku/Merc/ROM source you might be referencing originally tried to support lots of platforms in a time with standards were sparse.  Any C compiler from this century can remove all of the args stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as macros in C#, and with very good reason. There is also no corresponding feature. Thinking in macros means not thinking in C# and/or OOP. So instead of doing

```
#define args( list ) list
```

You would do something of the sort of

```
public class MyHelpers
{
    public static T Args<T>(T list)
    {
        return list;
    }
}
```

And then use it like

```
SomeType result = MyHelpers.Args(someObject);
```

Comment: FYI, I think `#define args()` was a no-op that assisted with macroexpanding arguments to the other `#define` macros.

Comment: You are quite right. I was trying to give a general example, but as your point points out: It just doesn't fit, there really is not equivalent to C++ precompiler macros in C#.

Comment: what about doing a delegate type development?  And i cant find any information what `list` is in the C library.  Any help on that?  When dealing with this type of broad translation between 2 structurally different frameworks, i have found that there are similarities between the two just the way you implement the same effect usually is longer with OOP (managed) vs the unmanaged code.

Comment: In simplest terms, macros are like mail merge. Code is replaced before compiling. In the example above list is just a place holder. Before compiling, all identifiers (left side) are replaced with token string (right side). In your example, "void    init_descriptor     args( ( int control ) );" turns to "void    init_descriptor     ( int control );" before compiling.

Comment: So would those situations where its a Argument list macro, could they effectively be transformed into Delegate?